# I want to update the specific fields in the firebase by using like a SQL WHERE

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

So I have this json data where I have

```
"User" : 
[{
    "Description" : "I loved to travel especially to countries such as Japan, Malaysia and Singapore",
    "FirstName" : "Josh",
    "LastName" : "Soh",
    "UserID" : "123"
}]
```

I want to update the fields of FirstName and LastName however I can't seem update.

I want to do something like UPDATE User WHERE UserID = 123

```
   $scope.edit = function (username,firstname,lastname) {
     var postData = {
            FirstName:firstname,
            LastName:lastname
        };


        var query = firebase.database().ref().child('User').push().key;

        console.log(query.toString());

        var updates = {};
        updates['/User/0/' + query] = postData;

        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about you data structure in firebase? In firebase it should be a json object and does not support array structure the last time i checked.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your JSON data like shown below

```
{
    "user" : {
        "2p4OmQqCdCbZzUMLC2BhMJK83jU2" : {
            "Description" : "I loved to travel especially to countries such as Japan, Malaysia and Singapore",
            "FirstName" : "Josh",
            "LastName" : "Soh"
        }
    }
}
```

Then to Update your data you can use the following code.

```
firebase.database().ref('user/' + user.uid).update({
    "Description": "I loved to travel especially to countries such as Japan, Malaysia and Singapore",
    "FirstName": "Josh",
    "LastName": "Soh"
});
```